# How to search in elastic search having an array field?

Tags: php, elasticsearch

My indexed elastic search documents contains a field which is an array. For example featuers of a car.

```
{
"features": [ "Anti-Lock Brakes",
              "Alarm", 
              "Air Bag Driver",
              "Cruise Control", 
              "Satellite Navigation"'
}
```

How can I search for documents with which includes values from a given array. For example: I want to checkout cars which contain features such as 'Satellite navigation' and 'Cruise control'.

I tried the following but it is not working (php code)

```
public function index(Request $request, Client $search, SerializerInterface $serializer): JsonResponse
   ...

    $search_query = ["Satellite Navigation", "Cruise Control"]
  
    $filters = [];
    $filters[] = [
                   'terms' => [
                       'features' => $search_query,
                   ]
               ];

    $results = $search->search([
               'index' => 'cars',
               'body' => [
                   'from' => $offset,
                   'size' => self::PAGE_WINDOW,
                   'query' => [
                       "bool" => [
                           "must" => [
                               "match_all" => new \stdClass()
                           ],
                           "filter" => $filters
                       ]
                   ]
               ]
           ]);
...
```

I would like get a hint on how to set the $filters so that I get the desired results.

Comment: Are you looking for PHP code or es query?

Comment: @Gibbs I am looking for ES query

Comment: Can you add your mapping too?

Comment: I do not have mapping for 'features', the data is added dynamically. I only have mappings for other fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you do not have the mapping for `features` and you are adding index data, so a default mapping is generated.

**Try this below search query, this will return all the documents that contain `features` such as `'Satellite navigation'` and `'Cruise control'`**

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "features": "Satellite Navigation"
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "features": "Cruise Control"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "my-index",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1.7178956,
        "_source": {
          "features": [
            "Anti-Lock Brakes",
            "Alarm",
            "Air Bag Driver",
            "Cruise Control",
            "Satellite Navigation"
          ]
```

Comment: @Utkrist Adhikari did you get a chance to go through my answer, looking forward to get feedback from you :)

Comment: @UtkristAdhikari thanks for accepting the answer, glad it was helpful :)